# LLR value computation : typical industry accepted worst case

Tags: performance

I am faced with potentially having to compute LLR = log(P / (1 - P) ) ,
where P is a given probability that a bit received is 1.

A polynomial "series expansion" for ln(x) is the logical solution.
However that will require a number of primitive sum/multiply ops
to get the value.

Scaling that to Gb/s rate, and that may be an issue.

I spoke to someone who works on coding function systems, and they said
that in HW impls LLR values are often defined as 8 bit items
(and sometimes 4 bits is possible) . So in terms of a series expansion,
this would potentially put an upper band on the number of terms
required to be evaluated before result "convergence" occurs.

My question is for a given :

- general implementation G of an LLR generator
- bit rate

is there an industry consensus on the max number of
sum/multiply ops S/M that would be performance tolerable, and beyond
which a professional would say G is not viable ??

Comment: For which decoder?

Comment: 3GPP coding functions (Turbo, Polar, LDPC) are the immediate scenarios.


Is your question driven by knowledge that specific coding functions could
for a given LLR value L, take values of L at lover precision and still arrive at the same outcome as with high(er) precision L ??

Comment: I am talking about decoders, not codes. For example, the 3GPP Polar coding scheme can be decoded using one of ML, BP, SC, SCL decoders. For your question, to the best of my knowledge, there is no such consensus: you need to focus on a specific decoder and, therefore, only simulation results count.

Answer (score 0):

A few points to consider here.

1. Bit error rate is a statistical metric. It's unclear why you have to update this on evert single bit that you receive. Depending on your measurement window, the difference a single bit will make is very small
2. The function is antisymmetric around $P = 0.5$, i.e. $f(P) = -f(1-P)$
3. The function is ill behaved at the ends, i.e. $f(0) \rightarrow -\infty$ and $f(1) \rightarrow +\infty$

Point 3 means that you need to cap it off at the ends to get a finite range. Where you can cap it off depends on your application.

For example if you can restrict P to between 10% and 90% than you get a good approximation with a simple polynomial fit

$$ f(P) \approx x \cdot (x^2 \cdot (a \cdot x^2 + b) + c) $$

with $x = 2P -1$, $a = 1.134282957587503 , b = 0.386208074094645, c = 2.023203373673901$ or thereabouts. This requires 4 multiplications and 3 additions and will give a result with an error less than 1 LSB for 8 bits.

Comment: Hilmar, thank you for the reply.

The function that computes P is not per bit, it is QAM-based.

So P = 64-QAM(IQ-V,SNR) , where P is a 1 x 6 vector of probability values, with each value in P corresponding to a bit in the QAM constellation integer value associated with IQ-V.